# Using MAX in a Filter range in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, max, formula

```
 Column A         Column B

    Joe             23
    Tom             102
    Sally           99
    Tom             111
    Joe             67
```

How to I output:

```
Tom           111
```

This isn't working.

```
=filter(MAX(B1:B,A1:A="Tom")
```

I am just adding text here because it is saying most of my post is code........blah blah blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend this:

`=SORTN(FILTER(A:B,A:A="Tom"),1,0,2,0)`

`FILTER` filters in just rows where Col B = "Tom".

The `SORTN` parameters mean "Return the top `1` results with ties-mode `0` (which is irrelevant when there's only one person) based on sorting column `2` in order `0` (which means descending order, i.e., max to min)."

Comment: Ok got it to work with your example....I just switched it around a bit to only show the highest amount.  =SORTN(FILTER(B:B,A:A="Tom"),1,0,1,0)   Thanks!

Comment: Happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you do it with max and filter:

```
=FILTER(B:B, A:A="Tom", B:B=MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, "Tom"))
```